# WebRTC peerConnection 'icecandidate' event listener not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to establish a webRTC connection using socket.io and this documentation: https://webrtc.org/getting-started/peer-connections. It looks like I have been able to establish a connection and set the LocalDescription and Remote Description but the 'icecandidate' event listener never triggers to add the candidate to one another. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Client

```
const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
const config = {
    iceServers: [{ "urls": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302", }]
};

async function makeCall() {

  const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
  await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);

  socket.emit('offer', (offer));

  socket.on('answer', async (answer) => {
    if(answer) {
      console.log("answer successful");
      const remoteDesc = new RTCSessionDescription(answer);
      await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteDesc);
      console.log(peerConnection);

    }
  });
}

makeCall();

socket.on('offer', async (offer) => {
  if(offer) {
    console.log("now sending offer: " + offer);
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));
    const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
    socket.emit('answer', (answer));
    //signalingChannel.send({'answer': answer});
  }
});
    
// !!! THIS CODE NEVER TRIGGERS AND 'peerConnection.iceCandidate' returns null
peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', event => {
  console.log('triggered outside scope'); // trigger check
    if (event.candidate) {
        console.log('triggered inside scope'); // trigger check
        socket.emit('candidate', event.candidate);
    }
});


// BELOW WILL NOT TRIGGER WITHOUT 'icecandidate' LISTENER

// Listen for remote ICE candidates and add them to the local RTCPeerConnection ()
socket.on('candidate', async (iceCandidate) => {
    if (iceCandidate) {
        try {
            await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Error adding received ice candidate', e);
        }
    }
  })

// Confirm they are connected
peerConnection.addEventListener('connectionstatechange', event => {
    if (peerConnection.connectionState === 'connected') {
        // Peers connected!
        console.log('success')
    }
});
```

Server

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    

  socket.on('offer', (offer, answer) => {
    console.log(offer);
    socket.broadcast.emit('offer', (offer));
  }) 

  socket.on('answer', (answer) => {
    console.log(answer);
    socket.broadcast.emit('answer', (answer));
  }) 

  socket.on('candidate', (candidate) => {
    console.log(candidate);
    socket.broadcast.emit('candidate', (candidate));
  }) 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The connection you are trying to establish does not have any media tracks (added via addTrack or addTransceiver) nor datachannels. Therefore you offer will not have any SDP `m=` lines and since the ice candidates are associated with those you won't get any and no connection will be established.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating offer you need to add track which you getUserMedia is giving to you to your peer connection  then you will surely start getting your ice candidate

```
        peerConnection = await new RTCPeerConnection(peerConfigration);

        setRemoteStream(new MediaStream())

        localStream?.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
            peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream)
        })
        peerConnection.addEventListener("signalingstatechange", (e) => {
            console.log(e);
            console.log(peerConnection.signalingState);
        });

        peerConnection.addEventListener("icecandidate", (e) => {
            console.log("Ice candidate detected-", e.candidate);
        });
```

Hope this will help!!!